# Conditionally remove rows from a data frame but keep missing values (NA)

Tags: r, subset, na

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),TEST=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,TRUE))
df

   ID  TEST
1  1  TRUE
2  2 FALSE
3  3 FALSE
4  4    NA
5  5  TRUE
```

I want to remove the rows where TEST=TRUE and keep the rows where TEST=FALSE and TEST=NA to get:

```
> df

  ID  TEST
1  2 FALSE
2  3 FALSE
3  4    NA
```

However, when I use `subset(df, df$TEST!=TRUE)`, R gets rid of the rows where TEST=TRUE and where TEST=NA. How do I keep the row(s) where TEST=NA?

Comment: subset(df, df$TEST == F | is.na(df$TEST))

Comment: Thank you Psidom, that worked like a charm.

Comment: `df[!df$TEST | is.na(df$TEST),]` also